# git squash several merge commits

Tags: git

I checked out a local branch, made several commits to it, and then pushed my branch to origin.  My boss wanted to merge my branch into master, but was apparently under the impression that he had to merge every commit individually, rather than just merging my pushed branch's tip into master.  As a result, our git history now looks like this:
[image: branch names changed to protect boss's reputation in the company]

Is there a "right" way to fix up the history so that it only shows one merge commit, that of my origin/pl/EngATSDataOnChkPrint branch into origin/master?  I suspect it's going to involve some sort of `git rebase -i` with some squash's, but I'm weary to try such a thing without getting some advice first (I'm better at git than my boss, but not by a whole lot...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR version: you *can* clean this up, but you probably should not, as too many people may already depend on the mess.  If it's only two people, maybe that's not too many; that part is something you must decide (preferably with them).

---

These commits are published, and you and several other people have picked them up (we know of two at least, namely you and your boss).

You *can* redo everything to produce fewer or no merges, but if you do so, anyone who has picked up the merges will have to do some work to adjust *their* repositories as well.  The reason is simple: git only ever *adds new stuff* to the repository, it never actually removes anything.<sup>1</sup>

You can therefore use `git reset` to "discard" some merges, then make new ones, but your repository still has the original merges ... and anyone who picked them up, *also* still has them, *and* may have done work that depends on them.  If so, they will re-introduce those commits when they merge their work with what you think you removed (but they still have), which means that they need to know *not* to merge their work with your sort-of-but-not-really-removed work.

Specifically, they will need to *rebase* their work on the old work, or on the new replacement you have put in its place, whichever is the case by the time they get around to this.

The same goes if you choose to rebase your work after, or as part of, removing these merges.  (Normally rebase discards merges.)  This is because rebase works by *copying* the old commits to new ones, with new IDs and new parent-IDs.

Say, for instance, that you have three commits and you want to move (rebase) them.  The first "moved" commit must be copied so that it can have a new parent-ID, and this gives it a new ID of its own.  This means the second commit must also be copied so that it can have the first copy's new ID as its parent, and that gives the second copy a new ID.  Then the third commit must be copied so that it can have the second new ID as its parent:

(before):

```
... <- o <- o <- o     <-- master
        \
         o <- o <- o   <-- yourbranch
```

(after copying):

```
... <- o <- o <- o               <-- master
        \         \
         \         o <- o <- o   <-- yourbranch [copies]
          \
           o <- o <- o          [abandoned originals]
```

If no one else has these commits—which is certainly true if they are *not* published—then copying them and forgetting the original IDs is fine.  If someone else has the originals, though, they may re-introduce them.

---

<sup>1</sup>What, never?

No, never!

What, never?

Well, hardly ever!

(More precisely, stuff that *appears* to be removed is usually just hidden away, where it remains for 30 days or so until git decides that it has been long enough to really recycle it as garbage.)

Comment: Thank you.  This is more or less what I was afraid of. And you're right, I don't know if anyone else in the organization has already fetched this repository, so I guess it's best to leave it alone and make sure Boss knows how to do it properly from now on.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`rebase` usually removes merge-commits, as rebased commits are linear and no need to have a merge. Just try and see results, use `reflog` and `reset` if something goes wrong to undo your bad experiments.

The thing is that seems the history is already pushed into a public repository (origin) so in this situation you have to do a force-push which is usually bad for a public history. If I were you, I would keep it as is. History looks weird, but it is not bad.